# Frequency mixing products

Tags: mixer

I encountered the following question on a test, and I'm not sure of the theory behind it. Could someone please explain?

> When a signal with spectrum ranging from 13 MHz to 15 MHz is mixed with (i.e., multiplied by) a 14-MHz sine wave, which of the following frequency ranges does NOT contain frequencies of the resulting mixed signal?
>
> - (A) From 0 to 1 MHz
> - (B) From 13 to 14 MHz
> - (C) From 27 to 28 MHz
> - (D) From 28 to 29 MHz
> - (E) All of the above ranges contain frequencies of the resulting signal

Comment: Can you elaborate why you are posting a multiple-choice question to this site ? Do you expect us to simply answer this ? Or maybe you do not understand the theory, in which case you could rewrite your question about what it is you do not understand, give more background what you have studied and researched about it and narrow it down so we can formulate an appropriate answer. As it stands it just looks like a question for some sort of test....

Comment: yep, I actually don't understand what you're asking here, so I voted that this question be closed. Please stop me by explaining exactly what you need help with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When two sinusoidal signals are multiplied through a non-linear mixer circuit, it results in the sum and difference of the mixed frequencies:

$$f_s=f_1+f_2 \tag 1$$
$$f_d=f_1-f_2 \tag 2$$

Of course, negative frequencies are not possible so $f_1$ should be the higher frequency in equation 2.

This multiplying or mixing process is also called heterodyning and is the basis for most modern, analog radios.

So now you can work through the formulas to determine your homework answer. Take note that the question asks for a range that would **not** be produced by the mixing action. If you care to work through the answer as a comment to this answer, I would be happy to comment on your conclusion.

Comment: Also (though depending on the context) it's often safe to assume that the *original* frequencies also appear in the output of a mixer.

Comment: @natevw-AF7TB True! An unbalanced mixer or a single balanced mixer are examples of that. Since the question is academic, I went with the ideal case.

Comment: base on the explanation above: fs=13+14=27 MHZ . fd=15-14=1 MHZ please advise me @GlennW9IQ

Comment: @natasha You are close but since you have a range of frequencies you need to add and subtract the upper and lower values of the range. The result will be two ranges of frequencies. Hint: one of those ranges is split into two of the answers.

Comment: @natasha I think Glenn's answer was on-point and answers the question. What further advise do you need, *specifically*? (Note: please learn to ask *precise* questions. That's how this website works.)

Comment: @GlennW9IQ      I will have two ranges on the most left from 1MHZ( calculation: 
shows (1, 1)MHZ) and on the most left I will have from 27 MHZ to 29 MHZ.  I think I got it right now. and option D does not have any of the frequencies

Comment: @natasha You have correctly calculated but you chose the wrong answer. The correct answer is B.

Comment: @GlennW9IQ  oh, yea.  thanks a lot